# How do I run commands in PyCharm without having to run the whole script?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a Python script with several functions and would like to run different `iloc` and `loc` commands to test different things. Since I'm new to PyCharm, I'm not familiar with its different functionalities. How can I run single commands without having to run the whole Python script?

I assume it has to be directly in the Python console. I tried, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Similar question: is there a shortcut to run a selection in the terminal?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

PyCharm has an `Execute Line in Console` command, the shortcut for which is <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>. This will run the selected lines in the Python Console if you have it configured properly.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Worth noting that while you can execute individual lines, if the lines cannot be ran independently you'll just get a bunch of errors.  e.g. Running `df.iloc...` by itself without any of the `import...; df = ...` lines included will have no effect.

Comment: @r.ook Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: I don't have PyCharm on this machine, but if it works like VSCode, it should continue to use the terminal that's already open.  i.e., if you already have the proper imports and dependencies loaded in the current terminal, you should be able to execute those individual lines no problem.