# Do I have to import excel file every time when I run the python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm an R user but trying to learn Python. 
When using R, once I run a single code to import excel file and save it as dataframe, I was able to use dataframe saved in my working space without re-importing every time.

While using Python, I noticed that unless I use interpreter, I only can run full script(whole "foo.py" file) but not code by code.

I would like to load excel file and work with data inside. My code begins with importing excel file as dataframe. Hence, every time I add new code and want to see the result, I am running all py script and it loads the data every time I run it.

Maybe I am using Python in a wrong way.
With Jupyter notebook I didn't have this issue because I was able to run the code cell by cell just like R. But I am trying to use Pycharm now.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('foo.xlsx', sheet_name = 'sales_data')
print("Column headings:")
print(df.columns)
```

Comment: Pycharm & Jupyter are different things, and thus behave differently.

Comment: Aside PyCharm/Jupyther differences this should depend on how you write your user interaction (e.g. python  (raw) input) or user GUI (e.g. Qt5 or tkinter). At the end of your script you can always actively close a file if you are skeptical to pythons garbage collection activities.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53452185/how-do-i-run-commands-in-pycharm-without-having-to-run-the-whole-script/53452229#53452229) for a potential solution to your problem, running only selected lines without running the entire script, similar to how you can do it in RStudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Jupyter` which runs a script line by line, and you have the variables including the dataframe which has been loaded to memory, so you can use that `df` until you exit `Jupyter` .
Whereas an IDE like `PyCharm`, depending on the edition, especially Community edition runs the whole script in one go, so it needs to load the excel into memory the next time it runs, because it's not persisting any information from the last run.

`Jupyter` is what we call a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), which means all user information is persistent till the session is killed, whereas `PyCharm` runs all the code in one go while it evauates things line by line, and give you the output at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

def load_file(file_name,sheetname=None):
    df =     pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name =sheetname)
    return df

readed_df = load_file('<file-path>',sheetname='<sheet name>')
```

then on `readed_df` to perform rest of task that you want to do .